# Ruby on Rails: What id do I want here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, button

I have a button in a partial that I want to send to the create method in my video_votes controller. The partial is in the video_votes view directory but is rendered into another partial which resides in the video view directory. My first question is, do I need to specify both the controller and action or just the action? Here's the button:

```
<%= button_to "+1", { :action => "create", :id => @video.id, :type => "up" }, :remote => true %>
```

Second, I'm not sure what id I should be passing to the button. The video model has_many video_votes, and the video_votes belong to video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= button_to "+1", video_votes_path(@video, :type=> "up"), :remote => true %>
```

Keep in mind that I don't know your exact route(I guessed on the video_votes_path), but run `rake routes` in the command line and set it to the one that points to the create action in the video_votes controller. You can pass in the video object to represent the id.

Comment: Oh wait, I never created named routes in my routes.db file

Answer (score 1):

The `:controller` part of the URL is derived from the current controller. So it depends on which URL you're currently at. So the answer is yes, you need to specify the controller if you're viewing it on controller other than `video_votes`. But a better way to do it is to use `video_votes_path` method to generate the path.

For the second question, you can pass the parameters as a hash. Here's an example:

```
<%= button_to "+1", video_votes_path(
      :video_vote => {:video_id => @video, :type => 'up'}),
      :remote => true) %>
```

Then in your controller, you can have the usual:

```
def create
  @video_vote = VideoVote.new(params[:video_vote])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why I should use your button code instead of Mike's from his answer?

Comment: @Justin: Just a matter of simpler controller code. My button code works with the default scaffold code, while with Mike's code, you have to add some extra code to handle the parameters. This is assuming that your `VideoVote` model has the `video_id` and `type` columns.

Comment: No `type` column, it's just an arbitrary variable passed to my controller method to see whether it's an up or down vote.

Comment: From my code, the controller code really isn't that complication, you can just get the video from: @video = Video.find(params[:video_id]), this is a fairly common idiom in rails.

Comment: @Justin: I see. You can also do `video_votes_path(:video_vote => {:video_id => @video}, :type => 'up')` if that helps. Another way is to pass pass the column value directly. Suppose you have `score` column, which can be 1 or -1. Then you pass `:video_vote => {:video_id => @video, :score => 1}` instead. Note that with this method you have to validate the `score` value, otherwise people can put 1000 score or something like that.

Comment: here's my controller code: `@video = Video.find(params[:video_vote][:video_id])`
      `@vote = @video.video_votes.new` Is this fine with Mike's code?

Comment: @Justin: That actually should work with my code. Seems like Mike's code doesn't generate the right path. When I tried on mine, it generates something like `/video_votes.1`, which won't even reach the `create` action.